# How do I select a radio button by clicking on a div in Blazor?

Tags: html, blazor, radio-button

In my project i have a couple of radio button groups where they have some extra information attached to them as you can see here:

```html
    <div>
        <div class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="Letters" value="a" />
            <a>Letter A</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="Letters" value="b" />
            <a>B</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="Letters" value="c" />
            <a>C</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="Letters" value="d" />
            <a>D</a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It works if i click on the radio button dot, but I want to be able to click on the parent div and change the value. I read that this can be done via `@onchanged` on the parent div, but I've only encountered JS snippets of how to do it.

How would I do this?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `<label>` elements instead of `<div>` elements to propagate the click event to the inputs. No code required!

```
<label class="option">
    <input type="radio" name="Letters" value="c" />
    <a>C</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</label>
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

> Alternatively, you can nest the `<input>` directly inside the `<label>`,
> in which case the for and id attributes are not needed because the
> association is implicit:

#### Demo

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/sr414t1n

Note: I have added a little bit of CSS to the `.option` class to render labels as block elements. The hover styling is just to show when the click will have an effect on the `<label>` elements.

```css
.option {
  display: block;
}
.option:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

#### Caveat

**Note**: strictly speaking, placing block elements inside inline elements is not allowed/recommended. Your dev pipeline / coding standards may or may not allow you to place a `<p>` inside a `<label>`.

#### State-bound styling

To style the outer label you could bind to a property that stores the selected option and then set a class based on that.

I have created a new demo showing this: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/56k8tfav.

I have created a `RadioOption` class to represent each radio option. I am then setting the selected option in the local `Selected` property in the `@onchange` event handler. This can be used for setting the `selected` CSS class on the relevant option.

This is just a pretty quick mockup to demonstrate one approach - you can choose to implement in whatever way you prefer.

```
@foreach (var option in Options)
{
    <label class="option @(Selected == option ? "selected" : null)">
        <input type="radio" name="Letters" value="@option.Value" 
               @onchange="@(() => Selected = option)" />
        <a>@option.Label</a>
        <p>@option.Text</p>
    </label>
}
```

(Edit: the CSS solution posted on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77823262/5367916) uses the `:has` CSS selector and is a cleaner implementation from a pure CSS point of view. You still might want to use my technique for cleaning your markup).

Comment: Nesting an input inside a label removes the need for that. I added a link to a quote from the docs in an edit

Comment: @Derek by the way, we don't use the R-word around here in the Blazor world ;)

Comment: This works perfectly, and i can just change the `<p>` for smth else!
Tho is there a way for me to style the `<label>` according to the `<input type="radio">` state?
I'm using scss if that helps...

Comment: @PedroCosta I've added a new section to my answer showing how you might do this. Dealing with radio buttons in Blazor isn't as straightforward as other inputs. You can reduce markup repetition by abstracting your markup content into a class and using loops. You could even go one step further and create a reusable component.