# How to customize parent class of an input in Blazor/Scss

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, blazor, radio-button

Currently i have a setup of `<label>`s that have an `<input type=radio>` as a child. This is done so that the label is clickeable and it selects the child radio input.

```html
<div id="content">
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="letters" value="a" />
        <a>A</a>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </label>
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="letters" value="b" />
        <a>B</a>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </label>
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="letters" value="cS" />
        <a>C</a>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </label>
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="letters" value="d" />
        <a>D</a>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </label>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to customize the label. My goal is to change the background color when the input is selected.
This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77821854/how-do-i-select-a-radio-button-by-clicking-on-a-div-in-blazor/).

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is to change the background color when the input is selected

Try:

```
.option:has(> input:checked) 
{
        background-color: #ccc;
    
}
```

Result:

[image]